# In FitNesse is it possible to override settings configured in the root page?

Tags: fitnesse, fitsharp

The [root](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.FitNesseWiki.RootPage) page in FitNesse is a great place to add configuration which can be used by every page.  Things like defining the test system or test runner.  Is there any way of overriding those settings, though, for a single test page or for a test suite?

I have a project using FitSharp (FitNesse for .NET) and have the appropriate settings in the root page.  Now I want to include a test suite that uses a Java fixture.  So, for that suite I want to override the command pattern and test runner defined in the root page.

As far as I can see, settings defined in a root page or in a higher-level suite page are not overridden when I redefine them in a lower level suite page.  Is there any way of getting around this or will I have to redefine the appropriate settings in every suite - FitSharp settings in each of the .NET suites and Java settings in the Java suites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest suites inside suites, so you can have two top-level 'container' suites, one for all .NET suites and one for all Java suites.  Define your settings in these 'container' suites, not the root.